# Desktop randomly stops working Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: gnome-shell, 22.04

So I made a Linux VM to deploy appimages and for the sake of curiosity. This is the third time I'm reinstalling the VM because at some point, it's just a matter of about an hour or two, then the desktop icons disappear (My system uses gnome shell), and it also becomes impossible to select on the desktop. The appearance settings that used to have options like "show home folder" also vanished. I can still access the contents via the file explorer, so it's basically a normal folder now.

Does anyone know why it's doing this, how to reverse it, and how to prevent it ?

Comment: Try some basic troubleshooting: Reboot the VM after the problem occurs. Check your logs on the VM Guest. Check for .crash files on the VM Guest. Check your logs on the VM Host.

Comment: @user535733 I can't find anything of use on the VM or in files generated by VMware which I'm using, everything somewhat related to gnome desktop doesn't mention any desktop crash

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar experience since upgrading to 22.04 and have fund it to be the "/usr/bin/gnome-shell" process.  Killing that process(should only be one) and giving it a few seconds for it to re-spawn seems to fix it for a while.  A reboot also helps but that is not always possible while in the middle of working on something.
Note: this process may also kill other processes, so far my experience has been it seems to be limited mostly to terminal sessions and documents.

I am still searching for a more permanent solution.